# Postgresql: How to grant permission for set role?

Tags: postgresql, role, sql-grant

There is user 'test_user1'. SET ROLE Command:

```
SET ROLE test_user1
```

returns error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied to set role "test_user2"
```

I couldn't find how to grant permission for SET ROLE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supplementing Egor's answer, in PostgreSQL, roles can be inherited or not (`INHERIT` or `NOINHERIT` option on the role).

If it is inherited, then `GRANT` means that you are granting all access that granted role has to the grantee role.

If it is not inherited, then `GRANT` gives permission to use `SET ROLE` to switch to that role.  In other words, `GRANT` gives access to the other role, and `INHERIT` determines whether that access requires a `SET ROLE` command to work.

Answer (score 11):

Error message

> ERROR:  permission denied to set role "test_user2"

implies that the command was

```
test_user1> SET ROLE test_user2;
```

, but not `SET ROLE test_user1` as you wrote.

If you are trying to set role *test_user2* for the user *test_user1*, grant it:

```
test_user2> grant test_user2 to test_user1;
```

Comment: This saved me with my AWS RDS Postgres setup. I had roles working perfectly in my local dev but when my app tried switching roles on AWS I got the error `permission denied to set role`.

The solution was to grant my roles on the default RDS role (postgres), e.g. `grant my_role to postgres;`